# Getting a JSON response from a REST API with VBA

Tags: json, vba, rest

Am trying to retrieve data as JSON with the following code, but am just getting an XML response:

```
Public Sub vbajson()
    Dim http As Object
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim authKey As String
    Dim accNr As String

    Set sht = Worksheets("Account")
    authKey = "abc"
    accNr = "123"

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://api.tradier.com/v1/accounts/" & accNr & "/balances", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & authKey
        .Send
    End With

    MsgBox http.responsetext
End Sub
```

msgbox output:

[image: msgbox data structure output tradier]

instead of using

```
.Open "GET", "https://api.tradier.com/v1/accounts/" & accNr & "/balances", False
```

I tested the following link, leaving the rest of the VBA code unchanged:

```
.Open "GET", "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", False`
```

and get the following result, which is the data structure I want:

[image: msgbox data structure output jsonplaceholder]

Am also getting data in JSON structure using the following Python code (code borrowed from here: https://documentation.tradier.com/brokerage-api/accounts/get-account-balance)

```python
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.tradier.com/v1/accounts/123/positions',
    params={},
    headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer abc', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
)
json_response = response.json()
print(response.status_code)
print(json_response)
```

Any idea how I need to update my VBA code to get the data in JSON structure? What is the issue?
I want to get JSON, as xml will no longer be supported once the API gets updated.

Comment: For one thing, if your request does not contain data, don't set a `Content-Type` header. That's the main difference I see between the VBA and the Python code.

Comment: Other than that this seems like an API bug to me. If you get JSON with the one URL, and XML with the other URL without changing anything else in your code, then it's clearly the server end that does something wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply. Same issue also with the removed 'Content-Type' header. Will therefore investigate with the provider.

Comment: On the other hand: If you can get JSON with the Python request, then you can definitely get JSON with a VBA request. Something must be different between these requests, and it can only be in the HTTP headers. You can try to use Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to inspect and compare the outgoing request headers in both the Python and the VBA request.

Comment: Not really sure what happend, did also not get a satisfactory reply from the provider. But my original code as pasted above is working now. Thanks again for your help.